# Stylesheet count from document.styleSheets.length differs between IE and Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Recently we hit the alert from IE on max stylesheets on a page (31) - more on that can be read here: http://bit.ly/1e8saOa

As a part of the investigation I [used a script](https://gist.github.com/psebborn/1885511) in the console in both IE and Chrome to see what stylesheets were in use and then combined the many multiple stylesheets to 1 in order to improve performance and not cause the error in IE.

**What I did notice however was that the count/length of stylesheets returned from document.styleSheets.length differed between IE and Chrome.**

**The difference was found to be many inline style tags reported by IE that had 0 rules and 0 selectors. These were determined to be inline style tags because ocument.styleSheets[i].href is not defined. Reviewing the source returns only 1 inline style tag ...**

Has anyone run across this with IE and if so have any light to shed on why it is returning these supposed inline styles that artificially inflate the totals that IE counts toward the 31 max? In my case it was returning 8 of these.

**EDIT: NEW DETAILS**

After further testing and research I found that each control, when added separately, added a  tag with 5 styles in it and another that was empty, with 0 styles in it. These were really defined in the main default.aspx for the site but it appears the AJAX loading it pulled these in. In IE, the tag with 5 styles was only counted once as it appears it determined the uniqueness of the styles within and didn't re-add it. On the empty ones, however, IE added them multiple times, one for each control, thus pushing the stylesheet count up. So if you are running into this type of issue look for any empty  tags.

Answer (score 0):

If document has more than 31 `<style>` blocks or `<link type="text/css">` blocks, IE just stops processing them after #31.  No errors, no warnings, it just stops.  Take a good, long look at the "Applies To" section as well. This bug has been around for close to a decade, through five major revisions of IE.
If you happen to use a bunch of your own controls or third-party controls that each emit their own `<style>` block or reference to an external CSS file, you could get screwed by this. The point is that you, the developer don't necessarily have control over what markup gets emitted by controls and you just have to hope that you don't use 32 different types of controls on a page or that the CSS for all of those controls are consolidated into a single CSS file.

[source](http://zenofscalability.blogspot.in/2011/08/stylesheet-count-limits-in-internet.html)